# GMSAutocompleteViewController iOS, how to change the text color in the searchBar

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, google-places

I'm using a GMSAutocompleteViewController and want to change the textColor in the searchBar but can't find a way to do it, I managed to change the some colors but not the searchBar text.

[image]

I've tried following code but the color won't change:

```
        acController.searchBarController?.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        acController.searchBarController?.searchBar.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        acController.searchBarController?.searchBar.textField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        acController.searchBarController?.searchBar.textField.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        acController.searchBarController?.searchBar.textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        acController.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.setTextColor(UIColor.whiteColor())
        acController.searchDisplayController?.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        // changes the color of the sugested places
        acController.primaryTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        acController.secondaryTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: hi please let me know how you changed the placeholder text and cancel button text

Answer (score 5):

For those who are looking for **Swift4** version, following code worked for me in Swift 4 (Xcode 9.4 & iOS 11)

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white]
```

For **Swift 5**

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: This worked for me. Worth noting it will change it across the entire app.
For Swift 5 it has changed slightly.

```UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]```

Comment: @Jeremiah: Thanks for pointing it. I have updated answer with your suggestion.