# GMSAutocompleteViewController iOS, How can I get different color for text in searchControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I'm implementing the default GMSAutocompleteViewController for my app. But couldn't find any documentation or guide to change the color of text in the searchController's textField to white. right now it seems black

[image]

I want it be white so the text is more visible.

**UPDATE :** I'm using following code to change to change the 'Cancel' button color to white as well but it's the same.

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
autocompleteController.tintColor = .white
```

Comment: primaryTextColor? from the documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912800/gmsautocompleteviewcontroller-ios-how-to-change-the-text-color-in-the-searchbar

Comment: I've tried that before as well as now... same result... @Ercell0 I think its for results that appear below after user types in searchController not the text in searchController's textField.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912800/gmsautocompleteviewcontroller-ios-how-to-change-the-text-color-in-the-searchbar

Comment: That was an old code... but, I've made an update to it in my code (i'm using swift 4)... should I post that as an answer here? @Ercell0

Comment: I'm still not able to get that cancel button to change to white color @Ercell0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this code :

**Swift 2:** as mentioned in the comments by [@Ercell0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361672/ercell0)

[GMSAutocompleteViewController iOS, how to change the text color in the searchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912800/gmsautocompleteviewcontroller-ios-how-to-change-the-text-color-in-the-searchbar)

**Swift 4.0:**

```
let searchBarTextAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)]
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = searchBarTextAttributes
```

**Swift 4.2. & above:**

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
let searchBarTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : AnyObject] = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.white, NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue): UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)]
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = searchBarTextAttributes
```